# How to visualize an entire sheet when using excel.link

Tags: r

I have a rather large .xlsb file which I am managing using the excel.link package in R. The problem is that, after running the below code it only loads a small part of the entire sheet I want to import and subsequently visualize!The excel sheet contains tables ranging from V22 to AR172, still my code will only retrieve the following range: V22 - W36.

Could anyone please help me?

```
xl.workbook.add(factbook_df) 

D1 = xl.read.file("factbook201903.xlsb",header=TRUE, top.left.cell="V22", xl.sheet = "USHP")
View(D1)
```

Comment: Using `colnames(D1)`, are you still missing last columns ? `View` might have a limit. Otherwise you can try `read.xlsx` from `xlsx` package